# How to Check Index Usage in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I create 4 to 5 Indexes on a given collection. Is there a method to see if those Indexes are being used for any of updates/deletes/selects ?

I know a method is use the cursor.explain / cursor.explain("executionStats"). This might be useful when we are developing a code. but once its deployed is there any methods to validate if any of the existing Indexes are being used.

I am trying to compare this kind of my experience with Oracle Environment. As Indexes keep getting pilled and due to changes in code people like to create new leaving the existing which may start impacting application over a period of time.

Bhaskar.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+which+indexes+are+being+used And the very first result seems to be a manual page. So if you know how to type in a search phrase it's a simple answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `$indexStats`, that will give some information about the usage of the indexes in a specific collection. You could try this.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] )
```

Within the output, you will see the number of operations that were handled by the different indexes you have. [Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/#pipe._S_indexStats)